# Detrmining open loop gain of an amplifier in LT-spice using a transient simulation

Tags: amplifier, ltspice, spice

Normally I would test an amplifier design in SPICE by using a method such as this:

[image]

Source: [Analog tips open loop gain](https://www.analogictips.com/measuring-opamp-open-loop-gain-spice/)

I would run a `.ac` simulation and plot the result.

The amplifier I want to design is a chopper and so `.ac` sims do not work because I need to find the open loop gain at DC and my DC signal is being modulated. This restricts me to a `.tran` simulation.

How can I find a DC Open loop gain with a chopping amplifier in SPICE?

Right now I am using a sweeping b source as my input
`V=1*sin(2 * pi * time * (1 + (2 * time)))` and a transient simulation, and observing the output, it is not giving me the correct open loop gain close to DC.

This is the circuit of interest for simulation:

[image]

### Real Question

My real question is how do I find the open loop DC gain for this circuit (on paper and in spice)?

Comment: Real answer: read the data sheet and design your end-goal circuit so that it does not rely on limitations in the open-loop gain!! I guess you'll respond with something interesting. That op-amp isn't a chopper BTW.

Comment: Which op amp isn't a chopper ? The one at the top is not a chopper, that is to demonstrate how I would normally run an open loop simulation. The circuit at the bottom is a chopper, the input is 'chopped'. It doesn't function like modern amplifiers that negate both inputs at a switching frequency (it only has one input so it can't), but it still fits under the definition of a chopping amplifier.

Comment: OK I see that but isn't the open loop gain calculateable from the op-amp data sheets? I'm struggling to see your problem.

Comment: No, it goes deeper than that. Because the amps in the circuit are not in an open loop configuration. One way would be to calculate the transfer function of each piece (the first stage has an AC gain of 120dB or 10^5). The integrator, is well an integrator, with around 30dB to 40db at 0.01Hz and 0db at ~10Hz.

Comment: Lets say you took both op amps at full open loop DC gain, you'd get 10^10. I suspect that the open loop gain in this circuit was measured on the bench. Now thinking about it I'd have to apply some comm theory (which is something I have only a small amount of experience) to deal with modulation.

Comment: @laptop2d The DC gain for an ideal integrator is infinite. In practice, of course, it's the open-loop gain of the opamp itself. And that's just one section of your circuit. Are you wanting to work out the open loop gain while you are also operating the LTC201 switches, as well? I'm thinking about perhaps the need for Middlebrook's methods, but where you apply a specific closed loop feedback to this, apply his methods and use .measure commands, and then extrapolate backwards to find the open loop gain. But I may be talking through my hat, too. That's just my first thought, is all. +1 for the Q.

Comment: @laptop2d Take a look inside LTspice's `Educational/FRA` folder. It has a few approaches to determining the loop gain in `.TRAN`, but it may require your simulation step to vary proportional to the measured frequency, for better resolution (shouldn't be hard to do it with `.param's, but it will take a toll in time). You may need to run for more than 1 period for even better results. If you can, also check out Yahoo Group's `Files/adventures_with_analog` (IIRC), there's also a FRA in there that has similar goals, but it may only work with fixed sampling/switching frequency.

Comment: @laptop2d I wanted to say this but I forgot and I was already on my way out. Also in `Examples` you'll find `LoopGain.asc` and `LoopGain2.asc`, where you'll find a simpler way compared to your first picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could break apart into stages, and consider separately. First, the sampling is 925Hz, so anything beyond f0/2 is simply ignored. Second, there are two paths, dictated by each of the two pairs of switches, \$Q\$ and \$\overline{Q}\$.

The first stage would be the input RC, that's easy: fc~528kHz, consider flat. When \$Q\$ is active, input is active, else output is active; both go directly into the JFETs.

Then there's the differential nJFET together with `A1` (they share the feedback network). Since the JFETs don't have capacitors around them, and since their parasitics would, most likely, go well beyond Nyquist, they're considered to have flat response, while the feedback network says you have a pole at \$\frac{1}{2\pi 10\text{k}1\mu}\approx 16\text{Hz}\$, with \$Av=\frac{10\text{Meg}}{10\text{k}}=60\text{dB}\$ and a zero at \$\frac{1}{2\pi 10\text{Meg}1\mu}\approx 16\text{mHz}\$, \$Av=0\text{dB}\$. Or write its transfer function as a shelf highpass (with R<sub>2</sub>=10Meg, R<sub>1</sub>=10k, C=1\$\mu\$):

$$H_1(s)=\frac{R_2}{R_1}\frac{s}{s+\frac{1}{R_1 C}}$$

There is at least a pole of the opamp which is beyond Nyquist, ignored.

The last stage is the integrator plus or minus the 1\$\mu\$F cap + switches. Their R<sub>DSon</sub> is considered too low compared to R<sub>DSoff</sub>. If \$Q\$, `A2`'s input is grounded, its output will be the discharge of the feedback cap. If \$\overline{Q}\$, input is a passive highpass with C and R<sub>DSon</sub>, terminated with R<sub>DSoff</sub> which is, normally, much higher than the 240k, thus the output will be influenced by the integrator's input, which will also change the overall transfer function. At this point, I  call LTspice to help and it turns out that the relevant transfer function is that of a highpass with fc well below 1mHz (~159\$\mu\$Hz, considering R<sub>DSoff</sub>=1G\$\Omega\$), together with a shelf lowpass with only the pole being below Nyquist, at ~325Hz (quite close to 462.5Hz), so you could write:

$$H_2(s)=\frac{s}{s+\frac{1}{R_{DSoff}C}}\frac{\frac{1}{R_1 C}}{s+\frac{1}{R_1 C}}$$

The overall open loop gain should be \$H_1(s)H_2(s)\$, depending on which path is active, \$Q\$, or \$\overline{Q}\$.

Answer (score 0):

Closed loop voltage gain= Av=R2/R1  So change Acl=from 1e3 to 1e? and compare offset error reduction to obtain DC gain.  Inject a DC input offset error if there isn't enough.

We expect DC offset error to be reduced by feedback Aol/Av, so raising Av significantly should increase offset error, thus Aol = Av*Vo  offset